# Assign pod an IP address which the same as the IP range of the k8s node

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, calico

Is that possible to assign pod an IP address which the same as the IP range of my K8s node?

For example:

I have an on-premise K8s cluster that includes 3 work nodes.
All nodes are using the 10.138.1.0/24 IP range as INTERNAL-IP. It is the IP address of the server NIC.

Can I use the 10.138.1.100 IP address in my pod?

I am very new to K8s, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you see [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)? How exactly do you want setup your networking? I suppose you are using [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/about/about-kubernetes-networking), but please confirm.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Yes, I am using Calico plugin. I tried to find the solution from service or ingress but didn't find the same case as my requirement. BTW, I meant the  INTERNAL-IP of the node, which means the IP address of the server NIC. Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the post.